# Visual Studio 2017 RC - C# UWP Project - Can't create class

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, uwp, visual-studio-2017

If I right click my Project and select `Add` -> `Class`, I only see `Class Diagram` and no `C# Class`. I completely reinstalled Windows 10. What can I do to solve this Problem? Before Visual Studio 2017 RC I had Visual Studio '15' Preview 5. There I could create a `C# Class`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/2558/no-c-class-options-when-right-click-create-file-in.html) in the current Visual Studio 2017 RC version and will be fixed in a future version. Select the .NET Desktop Development to be installed as well for now to have your C# code templates.

[image: Workload selecting]

Comment: This was already selected.  But the group below it had web and cloud.  I checked that and it seem to fix it.